# Create Django Queryset from Model and ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I want to create a queryset of the Plaque model and Veteran (ForeignKey) model into a combined queryset called queryset_list.

**Model**

```
class Plaque(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='plaques', default=1)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Group Name')
    veteran = models.ForeignKey(Veteran, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

**View**

```
def plaque_list(request):
    today = timezone.now().date()
    plaques = Plaque.objects.all()
    veterans = Plaque.objects.all()
    queryset_list = plaques | veterans
    # queryset_list = Plaque.objects.active().order_by('first_name')
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you're trying to do from your question and your view code confuses things further as you assign the result of `Plaque.objects.all()` to two different variables and then put them together. The `ForeignKey` objects on the `Plaque` model will all be available in the queryset. You can use [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to make sure you pull them all back efficiently, like so:

```
plaques = Plaque.objects.select_related("veteran").all()
for p in plaques:
    print p.veteran
```

N.B., the `.all()` isn't strictly necessary but I wanted to make it clear I was using the same query as you and simply adding to it.

Comment: I just noticed that I assigned Plaques.object to both...working with a head cold today.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the select_related method.

```
queryset_list = Plaque.objects.select_related('Veteran').all().order_by('first_name')
```

The detail is provided in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#select-related).